# Error executing a jar file ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I have been trying for hours on how to get this file to executive. On Windows it starts up successfully but on Ubuntu it does not.

My guess is that I don't have permissions to run the file properly.

Basically I navigate the the folder the jar file is located in with the 
Terminal and type in

```
$ java -jar Bot.jar
```

and I get an error saying

```
Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.Main
```

Ive tried using `sudo` before the command and using `chmod 755` but none of it is working.

Now like I said before this works fine on Windows and I can't seem to find what my issue is.

Comment: You most likely need to use the Minecraft Launcher to install a version of minecraft, which the bot will most likely use to interact with the Minecraft Servers.  Have you installed a version of Minecraft?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that there is no main method in the jar file. Not all jar archives are supposed to be executed. Some are libraries, some don't come with a main method on another purpose.

An example of latter is the Minecraft client, which seems to be related to your question. It purposely doesn't have a main method as a rudimentary piracy protection. For it to start, it needs a launcher, which connects to the Mojang server, thereby starting a game session, which is then handed over to the client by calling some method in it.

So if your file - I'll ignore the naming - is a Minecraft client, you need the launcher to run it.

If it is the other way around, and your archive is a Minecraft launcher, you need to tell it where the Minecraft client is located (`~/.minecraft/versions/<version>/<version>.jar`), maybe by adding it to the PATH environment, maybe by giving it as an argument to the command.

If it is a Minecraft mod, you should have installation instructions along with it.

Comment: Well that doesnt answer the question on why it works in windows. I checked the file, it does have a main method.

Comment: Oh and it's a bot I found on a website. Not minecraft itself. a

Comment: Check whether the class is as main class in the manifest and the main method is `public static void main(String[] args)`.